# App relies on sourcing secrets.sh for env variables. How to accomplish this in my Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh

I'm working on creating a container to hold my running Django app. During development and manual deployment I've been setting environment variables by sourcing a secrets.sh file in my repo. This has worked fine until now that I'm trying to automate my server's configuration environment in a Dockerfile.

So far it looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv

RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup

USER appuser

WORKDIR /home/appuser/site

COPY . /home/appuser/site

RUN /bin/sh -c "source secrets.sh"
RUN env
```

I'd expect this to set the environment variables properly but it doesn't. I've also tried adding the variables to my appuser's bashrc, but this doesn't work either.

Am I missing something here? Is there another best practice to set env variables to be accessible by django, without having to check them into the Dockerfile in my repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `RUN` step launches a totally new container with a totally new shell; only its filesystem is persisted afterwards.  `RUN` commands that try to start processes or set environment variables are no-ops.  (`RUN export` or `RUN service start` do absolutely nothing.)

In your setup you need the environment variables to be set at container startup time based on information that isn't available at build time.  (You don't want to persist secrets in an image: they can be easily read out by anyone who gets the image later on.)  The usual way to do this is with an entrypoint script; this could look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# If the secrets file exists, read it in.
if [ -f /secrets.sh ]; then
  # (Prefer POSIX "." to bash-specific "source".)
  . /secrets.sh
fi
# Now run the main container CMD, replacing this script.
exec "$@"
```

A typical Dockerfile built around this would look like:

```sh
FROM python:3.7-alpine
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR /app

# Install Python dependencies, as an early step to support
# Docker layer caching.
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install the main application.
COPY . ./

# Create a non-root user.  It doesn't own the source files,
# and so can't modify the application.
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup
USER appuser

# Startup-time metadata.
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/app/app.py"]
```

And then when you go to run the container, you'd inject the secrets file

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD/secrets-prod.sh:/secrets.sh myimage
```

(As a matter of style, I reserve `ENTRYPOINT` for this pattern and for single-binary `FROM scratch` containers, and always use `CMD` for whatever the container's main process is.)

Comment: Thanks for this, really helped me develop my understanding of what RUN does and why they say an image is just a "snapshot of a filesystem"